# Active Directory 3rd party authentication in .net

Tags: .net, authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have a scenario where user's of a Windows .net client app want to use Active Directory based SSO against a cloud service that the .net client calls.
The .net client should use the local user's credentials without requiring a sign-in form. The cloud service is not in a trusted domain.

Can this be achieved? 
Is there a method to use OAuth2 or OpenID Connect with the user's AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be implemented through WSO2 IS as Relying Party in ADFS. When we will implement this setup the outcome/Income claims will be main source for User Profile load to WSO2IS for authentication and pass the SAML Response to SP(End URL of your application).

Refer the below links to configure WSO2 IS as relying party for ADFS and WSO2 IS configuration too.

https://omindu.wordpress.com/2015/06/19/setting-ad-fs-3-0-as-federated-authenticator-in-wso2-identity-server/